# Entity Framework 6.0 Unknown Column in Field List Exception from Include()

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, entity-framework

We have a database first Entity Framework Model using MySQL and we are experiencing issues including all child objects in one query. Our database structure, simplified looks like this:

```
MDType
======
ID
...

MDTypeParameter
===============
ID                -- PK
MetaDataTypeID    -- references MDType.ID
...

Object
==========
ID                -- PK
...

ObjectItem
==========
ID                -- PK
ObjectID          -- references Object.ID
MDTypeID          -- references MDType.ID

ObjectItemParameter
===================
ID                -- PK
ObjectItemID      -- references ObjectItem.ID
MDTypeParameterID -- references MDTypeParameter.ID
```

We basically have meta data (MDType) which has 0 to many parameters (MDTypeParameter) which includes things like formatting, names etc.

Our live data (Object) has 0 to many items (ObjectItem) which are associated with an MDType. An item has 0 to many Parameters (ObjectItemParameter) which record user entered details etc.

An example of what data might look like is as follows:

```
MDType
======
1,'Book'
2,'DVD'

MDTypeParameter
===============
1,1,'Pages'
2,1,'ISBN'
3,2,'Total Runtime'
4,2,'Studio'

Object
======
1,'Lord of the Rings'

ObjectItem
==========
1,1,1
2,1,2

ObjectItemParameter
===================
1,1,1,'100 pages'
1,1,2,'SOME ISBN N0.'
1,2,3,'300 minutes'
1,2,4,'Newline Cinema'
```

When performing the following set of Include() functions using Entity Framework the generated SQL is incorrect, the LINQ query is:

```
entities.Object.Include("ObjectItem.ObjectItemParameter").
    Include("ObjectItem.MDType.MDTypeParameter");
```

But it produces SQL that looks like:

```
SELECT 
    `Project4`.`ID`,
    -- ALL OTHER FIELDS
FROM
    (SELECT 
        `Apply1`.`ID`,
        -- OTHER FIELDS
        `UnionAll1`.`ID` AS `C2`,
        `UnionAll1`.`ID1` AS `C3`,
        `UnionAll1`.`ID2` AS `C4`,
        -- WHAT THE HELL IS `UnionAll1` ???
FROM
    (SELECT 
        `Limit1`.`ID`,
        -- OTHER FIELDS
    FROM
        (SELECT 
            `Project1`.`ID`,
            -- OTHER FIELDS
        FROM
            (SELECT 
                `Extent1`.`ID`,
                -- OTHER FIELDS
            FROM
                `Object` AS `Extent1`
            ) AS `Project1`
        LIMIT 5) AS `Limit1`
    ) AS `Apply1`
) AS `Project4`
```

As I read this, it appears that Entity Framework is getting very confused. There is an alias table named `UnionAll1` which is never defined and it never generates any joins onto the required tables.

Has anybody seen anything similar or know how I can diagnose the problem?

The LINQ query used to get the above query was:

```
entities.Object.Include("ObjectItem.ObjectItemParameter").
    Include("ObjectItem.MDType.MDTypeParameter").Take(5)
```

Comment: Did you paste the entire query? UnionAll1 is usually an alias it uses when it needs to union multiple select statements together.

Comment: Apart from me omitting field declarations where it says -- OTHER FIELDS this is the entire query, which is why I was confused as the table alias UnionAll1 is never defined.